# JSF with Prettyfaces returning cached error page

Tags: jsf-2.2, tomcat8, prettyfaces

I'm developing a web application using JSF 2.2 and tomcat 8, but I'm facing a weird problem...

For example, I have a home page which will call a managedbean, connect to databse and return response. Everything is working, but, if some error happens, it's going to redirect to my error page (500.xhtml, which I set up in my web.xml file).

After the error happens, I fixed the error, but I can't access the home page anymore, it always redirect me for my 500 page. If, i change the the home page for something like home?anything it call my managebean again and works. Also, if i change the server, from localhost to my ip or 127.1.0.0, it also makes the request again.

Following, my web.xml. Also, I'm using prettyfaces 3.4, don't know if it's related but...
Tomcat server.xml and web.xml is default config.

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>JSF Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JSF Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>home.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.defaultResourceMaxAge</param-name>
    <param-value>3628800000</param-value> <!-- 6 weeks. -->
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<mime-mapping>
    <extension>xhtml</extension>
    <mime-type>application/xml</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>jsp</extension>
    <mime-type>application/xml</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>

<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/error/403.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error/404.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>405</error-code>
    <location>/error/405.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error/500.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>503</error-code>
    <location>/error/503.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

Prettyfaces:

```
@RewriteConfiguration
public class ConfigurationProvider extends HttpConfigurationProvider {

    @Override
    public Configuration getConfiguration(final ServletContext context) {
        return ConfigurationBuilder.begin()

                .addRule(Join.path("/home").to("/"))
                .addRule(Join.path("/home").to("/home.xhtml").withInboundCorrection())
                .addRule(Join.path("/company").to("/company.xhtml").withInboundCorrection())
                .addRule(Join.path("/portfolio").to("/portfolio.xhtml").withInboundCorrection())
                .addRule(Join.path("/contact").to("/contact.xhtml").withInboundCorrection())
                .addRule(Join.path("/admin/login").to("/admin/login.xhtml").withInboundCorrection())
                .addRule(Join.path("/admin/recovery").to("/admin/recovery.xhtml").withInboundCorrection())
                .addRule(Join.path("/403").to("/error/403.xhtml").withInboundCorrection())
                .addRule(Join.path("/404").to("/error/404.xhtml").withInboundCorrection())
                .addRule(Join.path("/405").to("/error/405.xhtml").withInboundCorrection())
                .addRule(Join.path("/500").to("/error/500.xhtml").withInboundCorrection())
                .addRule(Join.path("/503").to("/error/503.xhtml").withInboundCorrection());
    }

    @Override
    public int priority() {
        return 10;
    }

}
```

Looking at firefox debugger, network tab shows there was a request to home page (which was cached) and the a redirect with 301 code to 500.

@EDIT

It seems to be something with prettyfaces. 
I just remove it, and tested with chrome browser (without cache), after the error, i can access the page again. Then, I activate prettyfaces again, and the problem returned.

Any idea why that?

Comment: Obvious: you already did clean/rebuild/redeploy/restart?

Comment: several times... it's been a while since its happening...

Comment: It's at least definitely not HTML or JSF who's doing that. Just run the debugger to naildown.

Comment: I deactivate Prettyfaces (commented the whole class) and still redirect to the wrong page, but this time I got a 404 (because /500 cant be found.

Comment: @BalusC just Add an edit. Seems to be prettyfaces problem.